# Angular2 RC zone conflict with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, angular, zone

building a SharePoint hosted app with Angular2, it works if zone.js version 0.6.17 below is used. Any zone.js version higher than that will throw error "zone already loaded". It seems SharePoint already loaded zone before the Angular kicks in.

does anyone has a solution for this ?

Thanks

Comment: for updated Angular2 version (RC7), newer version of zone.js must be used

Answer (score 0):

Remove any script references to zone.js from you angular2 app.  I just took mine out of index.html because the angular-cli already loads it.

Answer (score 0):

Open `node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js`, comment out the line with `throw new Error('Zone already loaded.');` and build your project again. This works for the final version of Angular2.